# how do I get rid of "with()" in this function?

Tags: javascript, with-statement

since the `with()` function is deprecated, I want to get rid of it in my code.

How can I do it in this particular function?

#### Original Code:

```
(function(a,b){
for(a in b=a.prototype)with({d:b[a]})b[a]=function(c){d.apply(this,arguments);return this}
})(Element);
```

#### Formatted code for reference:

```
(function(a, b) {
    for (a in b = a.prototype)
        with({ d: b[a] })
            b[a] = function(c) {
                d.apply(this, arguments);
                return this
            }
})(Element);​
```

Comment: If it was actually your code, you'd know how to remove the `with`. Whose code is it really?

Comment: @zzzzBov it's originally from https://gist.github.com/1466219 but I modified it a bit

Comment: @zzzzBov: Why do you think it's important whose code it is?

Comment: Are there any comments explaining what this function is for? If not, I'd fire the person that wrote it :)

Comment: @JuanMendes it allows you to chain functions... example: element.appendChild(document.createElement("style").prop("innerHTML",".wqh{display:none}"));

Comment: @EvgeniReznik, because it's usually not necessary to mess with production-level code, instead it would be better to find an updated version.

Comment: @zzzzBov The problem is that there is no updated version or fork, so I have to make it myself =)

Comment: What if there is no update and somebody wants just to learn something anyway?

Comment: @EvgeniReznik, I have no problem with the question being asked, my problem was that OP said: "I want to get rid of it in *my* code" (emphasis mine). It wasn't *his* code, and I wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason `with` is being used is to close over the value of `b[a]` within the function, the correct replacement is with a closure:

```
(function(a, b) {
    for (a in b = a.prototype)
        (function (d) { //this line used to be: with({ d:b[a] })
            b[a] = function(c) {
                d.apply(this, arguments);
                return this
            }
        }(b[a])); //this is where `d` is set
})(Element);​
```

Comment: +1 wow - that is pretty **dense** stuff ... specifically the `for(a in b = a.prototype)` bit

Comment: Ah, I've never used `with`, so I was wondering how the code could possibly work, but of course it creates a lexical environment *(at least for the properties on the object provided)*. +1

Comment: @Xander but thus is *the original* ... I would not write code like that, but keeping it as so showcases how `with` can be replaced, all other code quality concerns aside ;-)

Comment: @pst agreed, neither would I. Nonetheless, it is pretty twisted and fun to decode...

Comment: @amnotiam, when I was messing with JSLint I looked through every "rule" and tried to figure out whether there was a case that would be reasonable and still break the "rule". `with` was a reasonable substitute for a single-variable closure in for loops for minified code where performance wasn't an issue...that is, until it was deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to say that it's almost too bad that it's going away. This is the first time I've seen it put to good use.

Comment: @williammalo: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/67Rcb/) *(in Chrome)*. In the example, the `appendChild` method of `document.body` now returns `document.body` instead of returning whatever was appended.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works! There is a mistake in the code above... Thanks!

Comment: @Xander, if you think *that's* dense code, you haven't been on [Codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1538/750).

Comment: @zzzzBov I forked the original gist and gave you credit https://gist.github.com/2009395